# Use of enumerated , zip method and iterates over the indices

Tags: swift

I am unable to understand this code and I want little help. Below example is from swift standard library. This example iterates over the `indices` and `elements` of a set, building a list consisting of `indices` of names with five or fewer letters.

```
let names: Set = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]
var shorterIndices: [SetIndex<String>] = []
for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names) {
    if name.count <= 5 {
        shorterIndices.append(i)
    }
}
```

Now that the `shorterIndices` array holds the `indices` of the shorter names in the names set, you can use those `indices` to access `elements` in the set.

```
for i in shorterIndices {
    print(names[i])
}
// Prints "Sofia"
// Prints "Mateo"
```

In the first set of code how can that `if` statement able to count names with five or fewer letters. Because `name.count` is `5`. and `shorterIndices.append(i)` include every value of `names` Set . I am new to programming and I am not able to understand this example. Can somebody explain it by line by line?

@vacawama check this out:

```
let names: Set = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]
for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names) {
    print("\(names[i]): \(name.count)")
}
//prints
  Nicolás: 7
  Martina: 7
  Camilla: 7
  Mateo: 5
  Sofia: 5
```

and now check this

```
let names: Set = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]
for (i, name) in zip(names, names) {
    print("\(i): \(name.count)")
}
//prints
  Nicolás: 7
  Martina: 7
  Camilla: 7
  Mateo: 5
  Sofia: 5
```

Comment: You are mixing up `names` and `name`. – `names` is an array and `names.count = 5`. `name` is a string and `name.count` is the length of that string.

Comment: @Martin `for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names)` this line of code assign sequence of  `names.indices` to `i` and sequence of `names` to `name` using zip method right? so `names.count` and `name.count` is equal i thought. so what is right?

Comment: Add `print(name)` to your for loop and you'll see it immediately.

Comment: What's a `SetIndex<String>`?

Comment: @Alexander Scroll to the bottom. Vacawama given the answer of your question. Check third one from the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to understanding this code is to understand what `zip` does.  It creates a sequence of tuple pairs from two individual sequences.  If you option-click on `zip` in Xcode, it provides this example:

```
let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
let numbers = 1...4

for (word, number) in zip(words, numbers) {
    print("\(word): \(number)")
}
// Prints "one: 1"
// Prints "two: 2
// Prints "three: 3"
// Prints "four: 4"
```

So logically, `zip` creates a sequence that if turned into an array would be `[("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4)]`.  Then the `for (word, number)` loop takes each tuple in turn and assigns a word to `word` and a number to `number`.  The first time through the loop, `word` is `"one"` and `number` is `1`.

In your case, the tuple pairs created by `zip(names.indices, names)` contain an index into the set and a name from the set.  The for loop looks at one `(index, name)` pair at a time.

The first time through the loop, `name` is `"Sofia"` and `i` is the index for `"Sofia"` in the set.

If the length of `"Sofia"` is `<= 5` its index gets added to the new array.  In this case `name.count` is `5` because `"Sofia"` has `5` letters, so its index does get added.

---

Sets are not ordered, so the names might not be iterated in the exact order you'd expect, but each name is paired with its correct index. Change your for loop to:

```
for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names) {
    print("name = \(name)")
    print("name.count = \(name.count)")
    print("names[i] = \(names[i])")
    print("-----")
}
```

to see what's going on.  When I did this I got:

> ```
> name = Nicolás
> name.count = 7
> names[i] = Nicolás
> -----
> name = Martina
> name.count = 7
> names[i] = Martina
> -----
> name = Camilla
> name.count = 7
> names[i] = Camilla
> -----
> name = Mateo
> name.count = 5
> names[i] = Mateo
> -----
> name = Sofia
> name.count = 5
> names[i] = Sofia
> -----
> ```

Notice that `names[i]` is aways the same as `name` because the index `i` into the `Set` corresponds to the name.  When this index gets appended to the `shorterIndices` array, it can be used later to retrieve the name from the Set.

Comment: yeah that example easy one to understand  and i tried too many similar of those but In my example then `i` contains `names.indices` and `name` contains `names` is that correct?

Comment: No, the `for` loop is iterating through the sequence of pairs.  You only get one pair each time through the `for` loop.  The first time through, `i` contains the index of `"Sofia"` and `name` is `"Sofia"`.

Comment: Ok i get that. but then what about that  `if` statement. of course loop will check one index and one value at a time. but if name contain value of set and not a index of set then `name.count` will count total value of set not letters of every index. This is why I am confuse.

Comment: The second time through the loop, the variable `name` will be `"Camilla"` and `name.count` is `7` because `"Camilla"` has `7` letters, so  that index will not be added to the array.

Comment: let names: Set = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]
    for name in names {
         print(name.count)
    }
I tried this in playground and yeah It shows counts of every single `String` value

Comment: Sets are not ordered, so the names might not be iterated in the exact order you'd expect, but each name is paired with its correct index.  Change your `for` loop to `for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names) {
    print("name = \(name)")
    print("name.count = \(name.count)")
}
` to see whats going on.

Comment: Thak you and sometimes I easily get confuse because of over thinking but Tell me one thing wht is the difference between when i try for in loop on  `String` value variable and same loop on `String.indices` ? It gives the same result.

Comment: Oh yeah that why swift standard library say use `enumerated()` on array and zip(_:_:) with unordered sequence or with two underlying sequence. So you are saying because of that zip method we will get count of name in ordered list? as value mentioned in Set

Comment: Yes.  That zip creates a sequence of a pair of tuples just like `enumerated` does.  The for loop grabs one pair at a time, a single name and index from the Set and `name.count` is the count of letters in a single name.

Comment: As you mentioned loop in your answer I tried that to already but without `i` I am getting one caution `Immutable value 'i' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it` and when you just `print("\(i): \(name)")` then see your console.

Comment: Yes, Swift is correct, since `i` wasn't used replacing it with `_` just throws the value away.  Look at my updated answer where I now use `i`.

Comment: @vacamawa yeah right and tell difference between looping through String vs looping through String.indices using for loop. I know they print same results but there is different meaning and reason for that. Something called subscripting. what is the benefit of real world and which one should use?

Comment: If you have no need for the index, just loop through the values themselves.  This is frequently the case.  In languages such as `C` you have to use the indices to access the items.  In Swift you can just iterate the items directly.  I suppose the reason to use the indices is that they might take up less space than the items themselves if you are storing them, so you don't get a second copy.  But that also seems dangerous because if items are added to the Set, the indices could change.

Comment: Yeah thats why I am so confuse with `String' because both method gives the same result. Let me add the previous example in answer then you check and tell me what should use with real world reason.

Comment: @vacamawa check my new answer. so tell me the difference as easy as possible. I am studying programming first time so I don't know about `c` language. Swift is my first.

Comment: In your first example `i` is an index into the `Set`, so you must use `names[i]` to retrieve the name.  In your second example, `i` is the name itself so no extra step is needed.

Comment: yeah thats totally fine. I get that already. But both thing given same result then which one should I use?  and back to our first example. As you said in comment they take less space thats why in that example they used `names.indices` to save names with five or fewer letters in `var shorterIndices` array. If you not so sure about reason then check this [link ] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2827905-indices) and then tell me what you think

Comment: Most of the time you will find that you don't have to bother with indices.  Just loop through the items directly.  Their example was a contrived example to make a point about sets and their indices.

Comment: Alright then. Sometimes I found documentation really easy to understand and sometimes don't. Can you please suggest me any book for Swift 4 ? and One last query. what is this `[SetIndex<String>]` in  `var shorterIndices: [SetIndex<String>] = []`  It is an Array. what kind of that syntax to create array. what I know is `var a: Array<String> = []` `var a = [String]()` `var a: [String] = []`

Comment: Take a look at *Swift Apprentice* from raywenderlich.com.  The Big Nerd Ranch books are also well respected, but I think their Swift book is still at Swift 3.0.

Comment: `SetIndex<String>` is the type of an index into a Set that contains strings.  So `[SetIndex<String>]` is an array of those.  `var shorterIndices:[SetIndex<String>] = []` creates an empty array to hold them.  It is the same as `var shorterIndices = [SetIndex<String>]()`.

Comment: Hey sorry I forget to ask you about second block of code of that example. `for i in shorterIndices` is looping through `shorterIndices` values and then `print(names[i])` is comparing and printing values ?

Comment: That code is simply looping through the values that were appended to that array in the first loop.  Those values are of course indices into the Set because that is what it was meant to hold.  It takes each index in turn, and prints out the name from the Set corresponding to the index.